# How do I path to a Python install using an Environment Variable from within an Excel / VBA macro?

Tags: python, vba, excel

This works:

```
Path = "c:\Python27\python.exe"
File = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Positionly-API-Keyword-Script.py"
```

This does not work:

```
Path = "%systemdrive%\Python27\python.exe"
File = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Positionly-API-Keyword-Script.py"
```

**What gives**?

I just want to make my macro more flexible so that it will always find Python 2.7 if it was installed in the default directory (which may or may not be C:)

Ideally I'd like to just variable/path it straight to Python to make it mich more flexible and rigorous in terms of error handling. I just don't know the VBA to do what I want!

Comment: try Environ function

Comment: Thanks! That led me to try this: Path = Environ(systemdrive) & "\Python27\python.exe" - but no dice, it still doesn't work...

Comment: add quotes like in the answer i have provided.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! Will mark as resolution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path=environ("Systemdrive") & "\python27\python.exe"
```

you can use the Environ function to get operating system variables.